# Prove that $1+\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m!}\geqslant 2\ $ for $n=2,3,4,5,\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I was given

> Prove that $1+\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m!}\geqslant 2\ $ for $n=2,3,4,5,\ldots$

I understand that $1+\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m!}>2$, but I don't see how $1+\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m!}=2$

Comment: did you try the first values $n=2,3\cdots,4$

Answer (score 1):

It's not equal to $2$. The word you are missing is **or**. For instance, it is also true that $3$ is greater than or equal to $2$.

We have a symbol for this. We denote it by $3 \geq 2$.